# Using sub queries in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider a sample query which uses two tables. Query would be like:

```
select t1.name, t1.address, (select count(*) from table2 t2 where t1.userid = t2.userid) as totalpoints from table1 t1
```

There are two bean classes named `Table1.java` and `Table2.java`. My DAO class extends `HibernateDAOSupport`. Is it possible to use this query with the two bean class in `getHibernateTemplate.find()` function call?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: let us know the mapping between Table1.java and Table2.java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The HQL query will be nearly identical to the SQL query. Note that your SQL is invalid, though. There is even an example of such a query in the [Hibernate documentation about subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries).